# Как удалить одинаковые строки?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Выполнял задания по книге и уткнулся в это простое задание. Не могу найти вообще никаких инструментов для решения это задачки
[image: пикча]

Comment: Где вы искали? А то один вариант решения содержится в главе, к которой относится задание, а второй вариант в описании инструкции SELECT в официальной документации.

Comment: Книга от Моргунова Базовый Курс SQL

Comment: Не нашел, либо плохо искал https://postgrespro.ru/education/books/sqlprimer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нормальное решение из комментариев:

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEAST(departure_cite, arrival_city), GREATEST(departure_cite, arrival_city)
```

Можно таким образом

```
WHERE a.model = 'Boeing 777-300' AND departure_city < arrival_city
```

При этом для каждой пары городов, между которыми осуществляются рейсы, запрос выдаст только одну комбинацию, в которой, соответственно, город вылета в лексикографическом порядке меньше города прибытия.

Если отношение не предполагается симметричным, можно использовать следующий код, хотя, может быть, есть более простые способы.

```
SELECT departure_city, arrival_city
...
WHERE a.model = 'Boeing 777-300' AND departure_city < arrival_city
...
UNION
SELECT arrival_city, departure_city
...
WHERE a.model = 'Boeing 777-300' AND departure_city > arrival_city
...
```

Comment: Нет, выдача не изменится. Потому что нет вылетов москва - москва

Comment: @eldario, например, Москва - Екатеринбург не попадет в выдачу, потому что Москва > Екатеринбург

Comment: @Mike Тогда да. Но если отношение симметрично, то это довольно простое решение. Если что, его можно использовать для симметричных отношений)

Comment: @Mike http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e2bef0/1

Comment: @eldario, решение работает в предположении симметричности отношения, то есть, если между каждой парой городов рейсы проходят в обоих направлениях.

Comment: @AkariGale я согласен

Comment: @eldario, добавил ответ для несимметричного отношения

Comment: @AkariGale На самом деле все проще http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/25d26/1 :) Можете добавить в ответ.

Comment: @Mike, блин. Клево)

Comment: В последнем варианте стоит одно из неравенств сделать нестрогим. А то мало ли у них появится прогулочный рейс Москва-Москва.