# T-SQL. Выборка уникальных значений по двум полям

Tags: sql, sql-server

Всем привет! Есть таблица вида

| From | To |
| --- | --- |
| Moscow | SPB |
| SPB | Moscow |
| Tomsk | Bryansk |
| Tomsk | Pskov |
| Bryansk | Tomsk |

Мне нужно выбрать все уникальные значения в обе стороны (поле Moscow => SPB равно SPB => Moscow), т.е. чтобы на выходе получился такой результат:

| From | To |
| --- | --- |
| Moscow | SPB |
| Tomsk | Bryansk |
| Tomsk | Pskov |

Помогите, пожалуйста, 2-й день бьюсь. Пробовал так:

```
select * 
from
(
    select distinct ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t2.[From], t2.[To] 
    ORDER BY t2.id) rn, t1.[From], t1.[To]
    from table t1
    join table t2 on t2.[from] = t1.[To]
        and t2.[To]=t1.[From]
) t
where rn = 2
```

Comment: надо пару упорядочить лексикографически, и выбрать потом

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/693409/223826 связное.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно так:

```sql
DECLARE @table TABLE ([From] nvarchar(50), [To] nvarchar(50));
INSERT INTO @table
VALUES
    (N'Moscow', N'SPB'),
    (N'SPB', N'Moscow'),
    (N'Tomsk', N'Bryansk'),
    (N'Tomsk', N'Pskov'),
    (N'Bryansk', N'Tomsk');

WITH TwoWay AS (
    SELECT [From], [To]
    FROM @table
    UNION 
    SELECT [To], [From]
    FROM @table
),
OneWay AS (
    SELECT [From], [To]
    FROM TwoWay
    WHERE [From] < [To]
)
SELECT *
FROM OneWay;
```

Comment: лучше условия сразу в юнион занести, наверное? а то так разуваем память, потом фильтруем. проще сразу отфильтровать и уже результат объединить

Comment: @teran, если оптимизировать, то да (хотя оптимизатор скорее всего и сам справится). Я специально не стал вносить внутрь, чтобы логика нагляднее просматривалась.

Comment: @teran проверил, оптимизатор такой запрос понимает и фильтрует до конкатенации. Это же CTE, а не временная таблица.